# Rails: Moving logic out of Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, messaging

In short I have some if/else logic in my views that I assume would be more efficient as a controller method or helper. That said, I'm not sure what the best way to go about turning it into a method is or the best place to put it.

I'm building a user messaging system into my Rails app. In my app a profile has many conversations (between two profiles) which have many messages. I'm trying to build the conversation index which will essentially act like an inbox. As a Rails beginner I'm not quite sure what the most efficient/best way to move the if/else portion out of the view is because it is operating within a .each loop. Right now my view looks like this:

```
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
<% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.profile.id %>
  <% recipient = Profile.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>
<% else %>
  <% recipient = Profile.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to recipient.first_name, conversation_messages_path(conversation)%>
```

For reference my conversations controller index action:

```
def index
  @profiles = Profile.all
  @conversations = Conversation.involved(current_user.profile.id)
end
```

And my conversation model

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'Profile'
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'Profile'
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages

  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
   where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end

  scope :involved, -> (user) do
   where("(conversations.sender_id = ? OR conversations.recipient_id =?)", user, user)
  end
end
```

This is my first stackoverflow question so if I'm not following any best practices with this question please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

In this case you are simply printing the profile's name based on wether `conversation.sender == current_user` or not. On your `Conversation` model you could have a `:display_name` method that receives a user.

```
def display_name(profile)
  (sender == profile ? recipient : sender).name
end
```

This is presentation method, so it might be better suited for a Helper, Presenter, Decorator, or many other solutions out there, but this should do the trick. On your view call it: `link_to conversation.display_name(current_user.profile), ...`

Comment: Thanks Leito, just for reference I had to use `link_to conversation.display_name(current_user.profile)` as the conversation is connected to the profiles not the user objects. I guess it's probably obvious for most, but it was creating some weird scenarios with the ternary operator since in some cases the profile ids and user ids matched up and in others they didn't. For a beginner like me it made it less obvious what was going on.

Comment: Good catch, I'm glad you found a solution for that problem.  If you take a step back is not weird at all for user_id's to match profile_ids's and that throwing an unwanted result. We were asking Ruby the wrong question. It was my fault for assuming current_user was a Profile instance.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would say your if/else logic is appropriate for a view; it's the query inside each of those blocks that's best to avoid. You essentially have what's called an n+1 query (you have n objects in `@conversations` and you query the database for a Profile object for each of them, and your original query to populate @conversations, hence n+1).

In the controller, you could load the sender and recipient like this:

```
scope :involved_with_profiles -> (user) do
  includes(:sender, :recipient).where(...same logic as your :involved scope...)
end
```

Use this scope instead of `:involved` to load the `@conversations`. Then you could keep your if/else logic in the view, but instead of querying for a Profile, you could just do:

```
<% recipient = conversation.recipient %>
```

or

```
<% recipient = conversation.sender %>
```

As these will already be loaded into @conversations from a single query.

Comment: Thanks Michael. If you get a chance do you mind clarifying what the 'includes' part of your scope is doing in comparison to my original `:involved` scope? Does it eliminate an extra trip to the database for each of those if/else checks? Or do I have that wrong?

Comment: Sure. It just includes those associations in the original query, so that they are loaded into memory with the conversation object itself. Then when you refer to it in a loop, it doesn't have to query the db for that associated data - it's already in memory. This is called eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine where it is.

Having it in a helper isn't going to buy you anything but reusability elsewhere.

Comment: I have to disagree, it works where it is, but it's not fine for the view to make that decision.

Comment: Disagree we shall.  No problem with the view executing that logic.

Comment: Respect, you hold your position while being polite, Internet could be a better place if all of us did that! I was/am (you are starting to convince me) thinking on "tell don't ask" principle (short read: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tell-dont-ask). The view shouldn't have to know about the internal logic of `Conversation` to display the user, it should simply ask tell the conversation to which user to display. But that depends on the current_user, so it should be outside of a model that only handles persistence.